# Alerting system for time series

Tags: open-source, database, iot

I'm using Apache Phoenix and Kafka to store time series incoming from sensors, now what I want to do is to create an alerting system using my data stored in Apache phoenix( HBase).

This alerting system as I imagined would evaluate a specific metric over a threshold ( single value ), then the result would be a notification via email or sms.

I have found those systems that suit my needs :

- Kapacitor
- Argus

the problem is that those systems are build to be plugged to influxdb for kapacitor and Argus is using opentsdb underneath

So are they any pluggable alerting system that can be plugged to Hbase or use HTTP to communicate ?